# How to load Home screen without showing login screen after login successful?

Tags: react-native, if-statement, stack-navigator

There are two stacknavigator for navigate with screens. I want to take condition for isloggedin or not. If loggedin user then select Appstack neither AuthStack. How to do this in this code? Is anyone can suggest me changes?

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    Welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header:null
      }},
    Login:  LoginScreen,
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Forgot:ForgotScreen,
});

const AppStack =createStackNavigator(
    {
        Dashboard: DashboardScreen,
        ScanScreen:ScanScreen,
    });


export default createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      App:AppStack,
      Auth:AuthStack,
    },
    {   
      initialRouteName:'Auth',
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you define, and export your routers, define and export a function, which accepts a boolean parameter 'isLoggedIn', and returns the respective router, based on the value of isLoggedIn.

```
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
    Welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        header:null
      }},
    Login:  LoginScreen,
    Signup: SignupScreen,
    Forgot:ForgotScreen,
});

const AppStack =createStackNavigator(
    {
        Dashboard: DashboardScreen,
        ScanScreen:ScanScreen,
    });

// This is the function that does the work, it will render
// the either Auth or App router, based on if you're logged in.
export const createRootNavigator = (isLoggedIn = false) => {
   if (isLoggedIn === false) {
      return <AuthStack/>
   } else {
      return <AppStack/>
   }
};
```

Then in your app component (or wherever you're rendering your router), we need to import this function, and pass into it whether or not the user is currently logged in.

'file-above.js' is the code above, i.e. the code you gave in your example as well.

Rough example below.

```
// We import the file
import {createRootNavigator} from './file-above.js'

class App extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state({
           // Switching this will switch your stack router.
           loggedIn: false
        });
    }

    render () {

        const {loggedIn} = this.state;

        // Here we're rendering the router, passing in the 
        // loggedIn variable from state, this will dictate if the
        // Auth or App router is rendered.      
        return createRootNavigator(loggedIn); 
    }
}
```

What is missing here of course is the 'loggedIn' field on the app components state switching, play with the code above, changing the value of loggedIn via the constructor definition, then go hook up to your login form(s), etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. I should change my code as you suggested. But it gives an error.  _ReferenceError: Can't find variable: loggedIn_

Comment: React native is new for me also javascript. can you tell me what is the remaining code?